# Rails new_all in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used code in a controller to update all records for a different model using an array of ids:

```
Expense.update_all({reimbursed: true}, {id: params[:expense_ids]})
```

Is there a way to new/build/create records?

Something like:

```
    Expense.new_all({reimbursed: true}, {expense_id: params[:expense_ids]})
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What would `build_all` mean? Build 100 expenses?

Comment: I believe I can create a new Expense with `Expense.new`. But I wanted to create a new one for each `params[:expense_ids]`

Comment: ids are assigned automatically by the database, which ensures that every records will have a unique id. It's very rare that you would want to create a new model instance with an id you've chosen. Can you explain where `params[:expense_ids]` comes from, and why you want to create new Expense instances with those ids, instead of letting the database automatically assign unique ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple attribute hashes to `create` to create multiple instances of the model. [From the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create):

> ```
> # Create an Array of new objects
> User.create([{ first_name: 'Jamie' }, { first_name: 'Jeremy' }])
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  My array is `>> params[:expense_ids]
=> ["42", "43"]` - how can I turn them into integers.  I tried `params[:expense_ids.to_i]`